# Georeferencing an image in R. When I change the extent, x and y resolutions become different

Tags: raster, r, georeferencing

I am georeferencing a number of images using R. I can read the image in fine, and set an extent:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)


## Read in the image as a raster 
my.raster <- raster("MyImage.tif")

## Read in previously gecoded maps
my.polygons<-readOGR("Poly.shp")

## Fix the extent
extent(my.raster)<-extent(my.polygons)
projection(my.raster) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

But when I look at the file I see that the x and y resolutions are off:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  3  bands)
dimensions  : 1935, 2511, 4858785  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0006940597, 0.0003798972  (x, y)
extent      : -91.81082, -90.06803, 13.84329, 14.57839  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 
+towgs84=0,0,0
```

and then when I start manually changing the extent to match the shapefile I have, it only gets worse. If I resample(from the raster package), it gets worse again.

Can I georeference an image and keep the resolutions consistent so that when I export it to ArcGIS or whatever, it is properly placed?

I am not providing files, because the project has confidentiality issues.

Comment: What do you mean the x and y resolutions are "off"? What do you expect them to be? Are those the real extents of the raster?

Comment: They are inconsistent. The x and y resolutions are different. 

Yes, that's the real extent.

Comment: Are the original raster georeferenced at all? If they are, the greater longitude resolution might be an artifact of the projected CRS the original raster is in.

Comment: No, they are just tiffs, not georeferenced.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. You have an image (raster dataset) with a fixed number of columns and rows. You can change the extent, but then the resolution *must change* because the (x) resolution is `(extent.xmax - extent.xmin)/ncols`. Likewise if you change the resolution, the extent *must change*.

My guess is that some of your assumptions are wrong. But it is hard to say without data. You can always provide non-confidential example data.

Comment: OK, thank you for your response. 

The main problem I am having, is that, although the raster file aligns properly with a polygon shape file in R, when I import the same raster into ArcGIS, it does not align with the same shapefile.

I suspected that the inconsistent resolution might be at fault, but even when I force a consistent resolution on the raster, it displays incorrectly. Perhaps that is a different question.

Comment: Could be due to a faulty CRS. Arc corrects for CRS differences in display, R does not. Either way, it should be very easy to provide example data.